# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute()

Tags: php, html, mysqli

So this is the code that's causing a headache at this time. Getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute()

Not sure where I've done it wrong at:

```
$mysqli_load = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$query = 'SELECT `id`, `call_taker`, `call_time`, `call_type`, `call_priority`, `call_location`, `call_city`, `reporter_name`, `reporter_num`, `call_info` FROM `calls`';
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli_load, $query) or die($mysqli_load->error);
$sql->execute() or die($mysqli_load->error);
$sql->bind_result($c_id, $c_taker, $c_time, $c_type, $c_priority, $c_location, $c_city, $r_name, $r_num, $c_info) or die($mysqli_load->error);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query) is returning [mysqli_result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), which has methods for manipulating result of query like fetch, fetch_object, etc as it is a result. Query has already been executed at this point.

The usage of `mysqli::bind_result` is at wrong place, it should be run on statement. And should be avoided altogether as it was removed in `PHP5.4`.

What about formulating it this way:

```
$mysqli_load = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);
$query = 'SELECT `id`, `call_taker`, `call_time`, `call_type`, `call_priority`, `call_location`, `call_city`, `reporter_name`, `reporter_num`, `call_info` FROM `calls`';
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli_load, $query) or die($mysqli_load->error);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // data manipulation
}

// and possibly close connection
```

No need to executing and binding anything.

For future reference, if your queries will take some user input, take at look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)